# Is it possible to create HVM AMIs from an amazon ebs-backed type configuration in packer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, packer

We are currently using an amazon ebs-backed packer configuration in our CI. Now we are trying to upgrade ec2 instances to t2 instances. But it only supports HVMs.

While trying to configure packer, I noticed that the ami_virtualization_type property is not available on the ebs-backed config configuration documentation.

Is there a way to use HVM on ebs-backed config?

Comment: t2s only support hvm so that might be the reason why it's greyed out: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a function of the source AMI - for example the official Ubuntu 14.04 AMI ami-df6a8b9b in us-west-1 is specifically labeled as HVM.